# Share data in every subview

Tags: view, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have created a layout which contains a header and the main content which changes regularly.

```
 @include('tshop.includes.header')

    @yield('content')

@include('tshop.includes.footer')
```

I have created the below view composer in order to pass the products in my basket to a pop up dialog in the header.

```
View::composer('tshop.includes.header', function($view)
{
    $basket = App::make('BasketInterface');

    $view->with( 'productsIterator' , $basket->getIterator() );
});
```

The thing is I want to share it in all views, including the main content.

I tried to use the `share` (and `shares`) function thinking that is the same as `View::share` but it isn't.

```
View::composer('tshop.includes.header', function($view)
{
    $basket = App::make('BasketInterface');

    $view->share( 'productsIterator' , $basket->getIterator() );
});
```

I also tried to use a view composer for the layout but in vain.

```
View::composer('tshop.layouts.default', function($view)
{
    $basket = App::make('BasketInterface');

    $view->shares( 'productsIterator' , $basket->getIterator() );
});
```

Next I placed the below filter to my constructor.

```
    $this->beforeFilter(function()
    {
        $basket = App::make('BasketInterface');

        View::share('productsIterator' , $basket->getIterator());
    });
```

And it worked, but I use several controllers, so it's not the best thing to do. I know I can make a base controller class and extend it but isn't there a better way to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `App::before` event to share some data to all the views globally using `View::share`, for example:

```
App::before(function($request) {
    $basket = App::make('BasketInterface');
    View::share( 'productsIterator' , $basket->getIterator() );
});
```

Now, you may access the `$productsIterator` from any view and btw, you have used `shares` instead of `share`. Also you may use a `View` composer instead of using `View::share`, like this:

```
View::composer('tshop.includes.header', function($view) {
    $basket = App::make('BasketInterface');
    return $view->with( 'productsIterator' , $basket->getIterator() );
});
```

In this case you need to use `$view->with()` method instead of `share`.

Comment: I've used both `share` and `shares`. I don't want want to share this data to all my views, just the particular one with the same header. For example contact me uses different header.